# Fail to predict with ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python

[image]I am trying to write 3 models to predict generation. But this error occurred in my third error when I include Latitude column which contains NaN value. How can I make this regression work?

```
feature3 = ['Panel_Capacity', 'Solar_age', 'Panel_Capacity * Solar_age', 'Financed_Yes',     'Panel_Capacity*Financed_Yes','Latitude']
x3_train = X_train[feature3].to_numpy()
y3_train = y_train

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse

#model estimation
model3 = LinearRegression()
model3.fit(x3_train, y3_train)

 #residuals
fitted3 = model3.predict(x3_train)
res3 = y3_train - fitted2

#model selection
x3_vali = X_vali[feature3].to_numpy()
m3_generation_pred = model3.predict(x3_vali)

#model3 - validation MSE
m3_vali_mse = mse(y_vali, m3_generation_pred)
print(m3_vali_mse)
```

I am trying to write 3 models to predict generation. But this error occurred in my third error when I include Latitude column which contains NaN value. How can I make this regression work?

Answer (score 0):

In order for a linear regression to work, you will need to explicitly decide what to do with these `NaN`/missing values. This kind of modelling approach isn't defined if one of the predictors has an infinite value - it can't give you a sensible output.

This will depend on the exact nature of your problem, but given it appears that you are attempting to fit a model of solar energy generation it is likely that that you will have to remove any examples from your training set if they are missing a latitude value.

There are other options for replacing missing values (like using a mean or median value) that can be appropriate in certain circumstances, but this depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have tried to remove all NaN values using dropna() function, but the same error still appeared. The original data set contains 3000 data. After cleaning it, 2985 data were left. For the latitude, 1/3 of the data is -27 representing Brisbane, 1/3 -33 for Sydney, and 1/3 -37 for Melbourne. I have uploaded the picture in the questions above.

Comment: The information in your post is not really sufficient to answer this question - you may still have missing data in your predictor or target variables, either in your training or validation set.

Answer (score 0):

## impute missing values in the 'Latitude' column with the mean

```
    mean_latitude = X_train['Latitude'].mean()
    X_train['Latitude'].fillna(mean_latitude, inplace=True)
```

## repeat the same for validation set

```
    X_vali['Latitude'].fillna(mean_latitude, inplace=True)
```

You can replace 'mean' with 'median' if you prefer to use the median instead.